PingException, how to get the reason for the exception?
I am working on a project in c#.  I am using Ping to ping a number of remote systems, sometimes I am seeing a PingException raised, however this in itself is not very helpful because it doesn't appear to give any reason why an exception is raised.
I've looked at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.pingexception?view=net-8.0
In the remarks:
Applications should check the inner exception of a PingException object to identify the problem.
How can I do this?

Check the InnerException property.

@SomeBody, thank you, did that a minute ago, problem solved.

To get the actual exception, use the InnerException.Message.
